# KissXML and GData Deprecated?

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, kissxml

I see KissXML and Googles GData are both deprecated.
Can/should we still use them ?
What are the alternatives?

I want to be able to read and write xml with an XSD schema on iOS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [gdata-objectivec-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) project is not deprecated, though Google is generally using JSON for newer APIs.

The library's support for XML is wrapped up essentially in one class file, [GDataXMLNode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Source/XMLSupport), which simulates Apple's tree-style NSXML API and builds on [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). While GDataXML is tailored to the needs of the library, it's usable outside of the library as well.

For your own app, it does not really matter if any particular XML library continues to be supported, so long as the library suits the needs of your app, and you have the source code to do any necessary maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Google's GData is deprecated. As long as it parse XML correctly, I don't see why you can't/shouldn't use it. I'm using it.